¿How can I send a command to chrome console devtools while broswing without opening console (f12) to enter command? ¿adding custom shourcut keys?
¿How can I send a command to chrome console devtools while broswing without opening console (f12) to enter command? ¿adding custom shourcut keys?
Any time I want to enter a command I have to Press F12, click on active textbox that is out of focus, then arrow key to select command, hit enter, then F12 to close window. All just to send one instruction. I need to send the exact same instruction many times and a combination of keys would be much easier than all this repetition of options.
